# Any other way to Refresh the page using ng-Route

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have taken a text-box to input the content and after the input , I have created `refresh()` btn to refresh. My code is working fine. But the part is **On the click of `refresh()` button , only the page should get refreshed** , but my code is refreshing the complete window. I tried using `$route.reload()`, but it din't work properly. I browsed through some sites, but I din't got the appropriate result. I tried my best to do it. But hopefully, I couldn't continue further.

My plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/0r7DXPWWtXmFYsHwY6Q3?p=preview

Here you can check it out.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by doing the refresh, maybe the complete refresh isn't needed, can you provide some more details on what you want to happen without refreshing?

Comment: In my application, i am using `edit()` and `cancel()` button. When the user , gives some input and wishes to undo it. they will click on `cancel()` btn, instead of erasing whole content. on click of that button, only that part of the page should get refresh and other part of the window should be stagnant @NarenMurali

Comment: @phione, Just store the edtiting variables in a dummy variable when the edit button is clicked and then restore them when the cancel button is clicked! can you provide the form you are using and the controller for the form with the edit and cancel buttons respectively?

Comment: @ Naren Murali I am Expecting like this : https://plnkr.co/edit/0r7DXPWWtXmFYsHwY6Q3?p=preview

Comment: if you want to update your page data without page reload, you shouldn't use reload, you have to update you data from controller!

Answer (score 1):

Why you want reload the whole page? You can do just clear the fields instead of reload the whole page.

```
$scope.reloadPage = function(){
     $scope.name = '';
  }
```

or trigger your page load function or code

```
$scope.reloadPage = function(){
      //You should call the function as what you did when the page load.
      }
```

**EDIT:**

*I know that functionality. But I have n number of text-fields. So its not an good practice to carry it*

> Then you should use with an object like `$scope.objectname={textboxes1,2.....};`

So you can easily clear the object like `$scope.objectname={};`

I have update your plunkr. please take a look that.

https://plnkr.co/edit/UxTNY1zgD4CrUEvERcHT?p=preview

Comment: I know that functionality. But i have **n** no.of text-fields. So its not an good practice to carry it

Comment: @phoine I have update my answer. kindly take a look.

Comment: but the thing, i have used `put` request for modifying the content. If the user enter something wrong data while modifying and wishes to cancel. The original data should not get erased, which is been stored in the fied

Comment: Use Temp variable while you click the edit button. But if the user click cancel button then reassign the temp variable values to original object.  that's all @phoine

Comment: i understood it. Thank you. could just try it in my plunker. Because, i din't got the exact clear picture off it